# Not sure how to return a function

Tags: function, lambda, scheme

How do I return a function in this problem? I'm assuming it uses (lambda x) but I'm not quite sure how.

Write a function (perhaps call it der for derivative) in SCHEME that takes a function f and a value for
h as formal parameters and returns the function g deﬁned by the rule
g(x) = (f (x + h) - f (x))/h

(As mentioned above, for small h, g is a good approximation for the derivative of f . Important note:
Your function should take a function and a number h as arguments, and return a function.)

Comment: Suppose `f` is already defined as a function;  can you write the function that takes `h` and `x` as arguments and computes `[f(x+h)-f(x)]/h`?  This seems like homework, and you're not going to learn much by simply getting an answer.

Comment: That duplicate isn't the same question exactly, but it does contain an answer to this one.

Comment: Also see [Derivative Plot in Scheme](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18902197/1281433).

Comment: Yeah I think so actually, I never thought of that! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

*Note: this appears to be homework, so I won't include a direct answer, but some notes on Scheme definition syntax and on currying seem appropriate.*

When, in Scheme, you write  something like

```
(define (add-one x)
  (+ x 1))
```

you're defining `add-one` as a function.  You could equivalently do

```
(define add-one
  (lambda (x)
    (+ x 1)))
```

because

```
(lambda (x)
  (+ x 1))
```

is a function.  You could write a function like `make-adder` with

```
(define (make-adder addend)
  (lambda (x)
    (+ addend x)))
```

which is equivalent to

```
(define make-adder 
  (lambda (addend)
    (lambda (x)
      (+ addend x))))
```

A call to `(make-adder 10)` returns a function that takes a single argument and adds 10 to it.  E.g.,

```
((make-adder 10) 2)
;=> 12
```

In general, if you can write a function of with *n* arguments, you can use [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) to get a function of *n*-k arguments and returns a function of k arguments.  E.g., if you can write a function that takes `f`, `x`, and `h` as arguments and computes the approximation of the derivative of `f` at `x` with delta `h`, e.g.:

```
(lambda (f x h)
  ;; [f(x+h)-f(x)]/h
  )
```

then you can curry to get a function of `f` that returns a function of `x` and `h`:

```
(lambda (f)
  (lambda (x h)
    ;; [f(x+h)-f(x)]/h
    ))
```